# Custom position of Meta Title in Wordpress <head>

Tags: wordpress

I want to change/swap position of meta Title tag in head of wordpress website. Currently, I can see the following code in my theme's header.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>">

<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
```

Looks like the title tag is being added in `wp_head();` function. What if I want to move/change position for my title and desription tag soon after `<head>` start tag or to any other custom place I want in head section. I can't figure out in which file the title tag is being added. So that I can change it's position.

Comment: Does it matter where it is located?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check `default-filters.php` file inside `wp-includes` folder. (*wp-includes/default-filters.php*). Find the below line and try to change the position of it and check.

```
add_action( 'wp_head', '_wp_render_title_tag', 1);
```